# При чтение из com порта (arduino) функцией ReadFile, возвращает непонятные символы

Tags: c++, c, winapi, кодировка, arduino

Если открыть монитор порта в `Arduino IDE`, то он выводит всё корректно в любом случае, вывод имеет такой вид:

`"sh0"
"lt1062"
"tp28.70"
"vl28.50"`

В программе на С++ вывод также корректен, если до этого я открыл монитор порта в `Arduino IDE`, НО если я отключу и опять подключу ардуино к ПК и попробую посмотреть через свою программу вывод, то получу такой вывод:

`"v"
"\u007F"
"\u007F"
"\u007F" 
повтор
"x~"
"\u007F~"
"\u007F~"
"\u007F~"`

И если я включу монитор порта в `Arduino IDE`, то и в моей программе всё начинает отображаться корректно, поэтому вопрос скорее в том, как работает монитор порта в `Arduino IDE`.

Моя программа:

```
HANDLE port = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM5", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    unsigned char dst[4096];
    unsigned long size = sizeof(dst);
    unsigned long recv;

    COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeOuts;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 5;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

    if(SetCommTimeouts(port, &CommTimeOuts) == 0)
    {
         qDebug() << ("Error of SetCommTimeouts");
    }

    if(port!= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (*abort)
                break;
            if(ReadFile(port,dst,size, &recv,0))
            {
                if(recv > 0)
                {
                    qDebug() << QString::fromLocal8Bit((char*)dst).simplified();

                    QString str = QString::fromStdString(std::string((char*)dst, recv)).simplified();
                    if (str.left(2) == "sh")
                        str.at(str.length() - 1) == "1" ? shake->setText("Трясёт") : qDebug() << ("Спокойно");
                    else if (str.left(2) == "lt")
                        qDebug() << ("Уровень света: " + str.right(str.length() - 2));
                    else if (str.left(2) == "tp")
                        qDebug() << ("Температура: " + str.right(str.length() - 2));
                    else if (str.left(2) == "vl")
                        qDebug() << ("Уровень влаги: " + str.right(str.length() - 2));
                    shake->setText(str);
                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(port);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << ("Error of Handler - INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: В программе, видимо, нужно выставлять настройки COM-порта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После открытия последовательного порта USB его нужно правильно настроить. В частности, задать битрейт, протокол 8N1, отключить XON/XOFF и т.п.

Пример кода инициализации можно найти в моей статье [Host-клиент Arduino на C (Linux)](https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/host-klient-arduino-na-s-linux).

Answer (score 1):

Добавил такой фрагмент и всё заработало:

```
DCB serialParams = { 0 };
serialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(serialParams);

GetCommState(port, &serialParams);
serialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
serialParams.ByteSize = 8;
serialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
SetCommState(port, &serialParams);
```

Хотя, конечно, лучше использовать готовые библиотеки, или код с сайта ардуино - https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows